# Error in adding audio plugin for froala Wysiwyg Editor using PHP Yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, wysiwyg, froala

I am trying to add **Audio plugin** support for **Froala editor** and I am getting error in **console** :-

```
froala-audio.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'POPUP_TEMPLATES' of undefined
```

The code I have added for `clientPlugins` :-

```
'clientPlugins' => [
  ......
  ......
  ......
 'video',
        'word_paste',
        'audio' =>[
            'css' => [
                \Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl([
                    '/plugin/froalaPlugins/audio/css/froala-audio.css',
                ])
            ],
            'js' => [
                \Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl([
                    '/plugin/froalaPlugins/audio/js/froala-audio.js',
                ])
            ]
        ],
```

I am using [this plugin for Yii2](https://github.com/froala/yii2-froala-editor) and [this plugin and trying to add for enabling audio feature](https://github.com/coassemble/froala-audio)

I have created `FroalaAudioAssets.php`  and registered in view using `FroalaAudioAssets::register($this);`

```
<?php

/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 *
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class FroalaAudioAssets extends AssetBundle
{

    public $basePath = '@webroot';

    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $depends = [
        '\froala\froalaeditor\FroalaEditorAsset',
    ];

    public $css = [
        '//domain.com/plugin/froalaPlugins/audio/css/froala-audio.css'
    ];

    public $js = [
        '//domain.com/plugin/froalaPlugins/audio/js/froala-audio.js'
    ];

    public $jsOptions = [
        'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END
    ];

}
```

After implementing above again I am getting the same issue .

Answer (score 1):

try change the position `POS_END` to `POS_HEAD`:

```
public $jsOptions = [
    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
];
```

Comment: Tried almost everything but no luck so far @Andre